# How to import the header file in dart via VsCode?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to import the header file automatically in dart via Vscodez(as shown in commented line for illustration)?
[image]

For  automatically way,instead of input manually

Comment: hover the mouse on the red line for example on the keyboard click **ctrl + .**

Comment: You mean quick fix?  Unfortunately,the right result was not listed as a option.

Comment: By the way,the "common_utils.dart "was from a package named "common_utils"